# Let scroll to top button stick above footer/credits

Tags: html, jquery, css

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > $(window).height()) {
            $('#scroll-top').fadeIn(300);
            $('#scroll-top').css('display', 'flex');
        } else {
            $('#scroll-top').fadeOut(300);
        }
    });

    //Click event to scroll to top
    $('#scroll-top').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
        return false;
    });

    //If Cookie-container is visable add bottom value
    if ($("#cookie-notification-container").is(':visible')){
    $("#scroll-top").css('bottom', 80 + 'px');
    } else {
        $("#scroll-top").css('bottom', '20px');}

});
```

```css
/* ======================================================
    ► SCROLL-TOP
   ====================================================== */

#scroll-top{
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 99;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #ff91a2 0%,#ffabb7 100%);
    background: <?= $headerBackgroundColor; ?>;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#scroll-top::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    border-radius: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: scale(0);
    transform-origin: center;
    transition: transform 0.25s, border-radius 0.25s, background 0.25s;
}

#scroll-top:hover::after{
    transform: scale(1);
    border-radius: 100%;
    transform-origin: center;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.15);
}

#scroll-top svg{
    transform: translateY(0%);
    opacity: 1;
    animation: fade-up 0.4s ease-out;
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
    animation-fill-mode: backwards;
    fill:#ffffff;
}

@keyframes fade-up{
    0%{transform: translateY(80%); opacity:0 ;}
    80%{opacity:1 ;}
    100%{transform: translateY(0%); opacity:1 ;}
}

/* ======================================================
    ► CREDITS
   ====================================================== */

#credits-container{
    background: #2D2C2B;
    min-height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

#credits-container .wrapper #credits{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  min-height: 60px;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
}

#credits-container .wrapper #credits p{
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    letter-spacing: 0.005em;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    line-height: 1.2;
    display: block;
    margin: 0em 0;
    margin-block-start: 0em;
    margin-block-end: 0em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
    text-align:center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
#credits-container .wrapper #credits p{
    font-size: 0.90em;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height: 2000px;">
<button id="scroll-top" onclick="topFunction()">
    <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 800 460" width="15" height="15">
    <path d="M782.45,357.08l-340-340a60.07,60.07,0,0,0-84.86,0l-340,340a60,60,0,0,0,84.86,84.86L400,144.35,697.59,441.94a60,60,0,0,0,84.86-84.86Z" transform="translate(0 0.49)"/>
</svg>
</button>

</div>
<div id="credits-container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="credits">
            <p>Created by Jhon Doh - ©<?= date("Y");?> Test Design.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a scroll to top button that I would like to stick above the footer/credits (let it float 20 px above the credits/footer). When I apply sticky instead of fixed it does not work properly. I was wondering if someone could help me out. I am pretty new with this stuff. I have tried something similar with the cookie notification in the script(See below). But it is a bad temporary solution.

Comment: "sticky" is a position property, and "flex" is display property. They are doing completely different things. Based on your code, you are actually switching from position absolute (set in your styles) to sticky (when you apply it in JS). There is nothing wrong with your solution for cookie notification. If you want to improve it, maybe don't hard code the value 80px (because you might change it later) - instead, read the height of the cookie notification and pass that value to #scroll-top's bottom position.

Btw, what's the height of the footer? 20px?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant "fixed" not "flex". I edited it. The height of the footer is not yet determined, the credits have a min-height of 60 px.

Comment: Maybe I don't see the specific edge case you're trying to solve, but it seems that you don't need "sticky" for this to work. Fixed position should be just fine. I would simply store footer/cookie container height in a variable called bottomOffset and use it programatically instead of hard coding those values. One more improvement, you can add `transition: bottom .3s ease-out` to make make things a bit smoother :)

If you can put this code in some sandbox or jsfiddle and make it interactive, I'd be able to help you more. Does this so far answer your question at all?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help! I am learning a lot here

Comment: You are welcome. Another important aspect of this is: does footer (and cookie container) stay in the natural flow of the document or you intend to give them `position: fixed` or absolute? I might try to abstract this UI in a codepen.

Comment: The footer/credits stay in the natural flow of the document. They have a position of relative and a display of flex.